# Making A system as Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, client-server

How Can I use my system as a tomcat server ?
Like tomcat server will be running in my system, a web application is placed in CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory.

how can I run a web application in different client machines located somewhere ?
People usually deploy their web application in their web host, but I just wanted to use my personal computer as a server for learning purpose.

Can any one please give me the steps to achieve this ?

Regards,
Sadanand

Comment: Start your Tomcat, Deploy the application, and distribute the links for accessing.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you edit it (use the "edit" link underneath it) to explain more thoroughly what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make my system as a tomcat server?

Assuming that you are able to write your server in Java using Servlet technologies, yes you can.

A good place to start would be to read the [Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) on the Tomcat website.  Start with sections 1), 2) and 3).

---

The requirements for a website to be accessible from anywhere are:

- A public IP address for your server; i.e. not one that is sitting on a private network with a private IP address.
- A registered public DNS name that allows you to refer to your server / site by name.  (This is not strictly necessary, but it is a good idea.  People tend not to trust sites without a DNS name, and besides names are easier to remember.)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is enough:

- lightweight
- easy-to-setup

so that it can run on every client machine. 
If the "client-machine" wants to use Tomcat for development means, one should be aware how to setup web-container/application server and how to configure most basic parameters.

If one is only to access Tomcat resource via URL, you need to have public IP/hostname.